# BLToolkit: Can't make ScalarSource in DataAccessor work

Tags: sql, bltoolkit

I have SP like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pPersonGetIDByName
@Name nvarchar(50),
@ID int output
AS ...
```

and appropriate DataAccessor method

```
[ScalarSource(ScalarSourceType.OutputParameter)]
abstract int GetIDByName(string Name);
```

I understand it as 'call stored procedure, pass Name parameter and return me first output parameter as a result'. But this call

```
id = pa.GetIDByName("testname");
```

Returns me error

> Procedure or function 'pPersonGetIDByName' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.

As far as I can see in examples (OutputParameterTest()) it should be OK. SQL Server call is correct:

```
declare @p2 int
set @p2=default
exec pPersonGetIDByName @Name=N'testname',@ID=@p2 output
select @p2
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the parameter name :

```
[ScalarSource(ScalarSourceType.OutputParameter, "ID")]
abstract int GetIDByName(string Name);
```